# How to build screens properly in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, flutter-layout

I am new to flutter and I need help in rendering screens in proper order.

I am creating a chat app, where previoulsly, there was a chat overview screen, and, if anyone clicks on a "chat room tile", he/she goes to that particular chat room's screen. And from inside, if the back button is pressed with Navigator.pop(), he/she would land up again on the chat overview screen.

Everything was working fine until now.

But after addng local notifications, when a user directly goes to a particular chat room's screen after clicking the notification from the notification shade, the back button with navigator.pop in the chat room's screen is not working.
I have also tried to use Navigator.pushReplacementNamed() to render the chat overview screen when back button is clicked, but the bottom tab bar of the app is not appearing in that case.

```html
class ChatOverviewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChatOverviewScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ChatOverviewScreen> createState() => _ChatOverviewScreenState();
}

class _ChatOverviewScreenState extends State<ChatOverviewScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          Constants.appName,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Constants.textPrimary,
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Session().clearSession();
              Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, Routes.authHomeScreen);
            },
            child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Logout',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, fontSize: 15),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
        backgroundColor: Constants.backgroundPrimary,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const ChatFetchingIndicator(),
            Expanded(
              child: BlocBuilder<ChatBloc, ChatState>(
                builder: (context, state) {
                  return Container(
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(
                        minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height),
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        ChatRoomWithLastChat chatRoomWithLastChat =
                            state.chatRooms[index];
                        ID friendId = chatRoomWithLastChat.friendId;

                        FullName friendName = chatRoomWithLastChat.friendName;

                        SecureURL? friendAvatar =
                            chatRoomWithLastChat.friendAvatar;

                        return ChatTile(
                          friendName: friendName,
                          lastText:
                              chatRoomWithLastChat.lastChat?.message ?? "",
                          lastMessageTime: chatRoomWithLastChat.lastChatTime,
                          friendId: friendId,
                          lastChatStatus:
                              chatRoomWithLastChat.lastChat?.status ??
                                  ChatStatus.pending,
                          isLastTextMine:
                              chatRoomWithLastChat.lastChat?.senderId ==
                                      friendId
                                  ? false
                                  : true,
                          friendAvatar: friendAvatar,
                          unreadCount: chatRoomWithLastChat.unreadCount,
                        );
                      },
                      itemCount: state.chatRooms.length,
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**CHAT SCREEN**

```html
class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final ID friendId;
  final SecureURL friendAvatar;
  final FullName friendName;

  const ChatScreen({
    Key? key,
    required this.friendId,
    required this.friendAvatar,
    required this.friendName,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ChatScreen> createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  final TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.of(context).p
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new),
          onPressed: () {
            BlocProvider.of<ChatBloc>(context).add(const ResetActiveChatRoom());
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
        title: Row(
          children: [
            CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(widget.friendAvatar.toString()),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              width: 15,
            ),
            Text(widget.friendName.value.getOrElse(() => "Unknown User")),
          ],
        ),
        actions: const [
          Icon(Icons.more_vert_sharp),
          SizedBox(
            width: 10.0,
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          ChatsContainer(
            friendId: widget.friendId,
            friendName: widget.friendName,
            scrollController: _scrollController,
          ),
          ChatTextField(
            sendMessage: sendMessage,
            scrollController: _scrollController,
            controller: _textEditingController,
            receiverId: widget.friendId,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    _textEditingController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void sendMessage(ID receiverId) {
    try {
      if (_textEditingController.text.isNotEmpty) {
        SendChatInput sendChatInput = SendChatInput.of(
            senderId: context.read<UserCubit>().state.user.id,
            receiverId: receiverId,
            message: _textEditingController.text);

        BlocProvider.of<ChatBloc>(context).add(SendChat(sendChatInput));

        _textEditingController.clear();
        // _scrollController.animateTo(
        //   _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
        //   duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        //   curve: Curves.easeInExpo,
        // );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw ErrorDescription(e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code for both the screens?

Comment: Hi, I have added them in the main question.

Answer (score 0):

Create a parameter with data type boolean in ChatOverview Screen & When User opens up the notification instead of opening chat screen directly,

1. Call Chat Overview Screen & pass boolean parameter - true.
2. Call Chat Screen from Overview Screen when boolean is true.

```
class ChatOverviewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool isFromNotification;
  const ChatOverviewScreen({Key? key,this.isFromNotification = false}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ChatOverviewScreen> createState() => _ChatOverviewScreenState();
}

class _ChatOverviewScreenState extends State<ChatOverviewScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  
  if(widget.isFromNotification){
  // navigate to Chat Screen
  }
  
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          Constants.appName,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Constants.textPrimary,
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Session().clearSession();
              Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, Routes.authHomeScreen);
            },
            child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Logout',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, fontSize: 15),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
        backgroundColor: Constants.backgroundPrimary,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const ChatFetchingIndicator(),
            Expanded(
              child: BlocBuilder<ChatBloc, ChatState>(
                builder: (context, state) {
                  return Container(
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(
                        minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height),
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        ChatRoomWithLastChat chatRoomWithLastChat =
                            state.chatRooms[index];
                        ID friendId = chatRoomWithLastChat.friendId;

                        FullName friendName = chatRoomWithLastChat.friendName;

                        SecureURL? friendAvatar =
                            chatRoomWithLastChat.friendAvatar;

                        return ChatTile(
                          friendName: friendName,
                          lastText:
                              chatRoomWithLastChat.lastChat?.message ?? "",
                          lastMessageTime: chatRoomWithLastChat.lastChatTime,
                          friendId: friendId,
                          lastChatStatus:
                              chatRoomWithLastChat.lastChat?.status ??
                                  ChatStatus.pending,
                          isLastTextMine:
                              chatRoomWithLastChat.lastChat?.senderId ==
                                      friendId
                                  ? false
                                  : true,
                          friendAvatar: friendAvatar,
                          unreadCount: chatRoomWithLastChat.unreadCount,
                        );
                      },
                      itemCount: state.chatRooms.length,
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**By doing this you can directly pop out from Chat Screen, no need to use Navigator.pushReplacementNamed() on Back Button**

Comment: I had tried that and the main issue was that the bottom tab bar was not appearing in this case as the chat overview screen was generally rendered as the 2nd index from a home screen which contains the chat overview screen

Comment: Also, if I follow the path like home > chat overview -> chat screen, my goal can be achieved but, from performance point of view, it seems bad